Session ends abruptly when disconnecting HDMI cable (Ubuntu 24.04)
I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04 and realized that everytime I disconnect the external monitor (HDMI), the Gnome session ends abruptly and the login screen is shown. On Ubuntu 23.10 that didn´t use to happen.
I'm using wayland.
All opened apps are killed too.
How to reproduce:

Start graphical user session (login) with external monitor connected
Disconnect HDMI cable

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Regards

I have something similar. I noticed the crash only happens when there's a window in the extended desktop. If I remove all windows from it, I can unplug without crashing the session

Having same issue

Same here with X11. Ubuntu 24. :(

Same issue here on Ubuntu 24.04 updated from 22.04 LTS.

I was having the same problem.
It seems to be a problem with the Ubuntu tiling assistant extension and/or the library mutter. I've found a discussion about it here.
As presented in the bug report, there are two steps to solve it:

Disable the "Ubuntu tiling assistant" extension.
Install manually an update of mutter from 46.0 to 46.1. To do so (still from here):


wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/46.1-2ubuntu1/+build/28374184/+files/gir1.2-mutter-14_46.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/46.1-2ubuntu1/+build/28374184/+files/libmutter-14-0_46.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/46.1-2ubuntu1/+build/28374184/+files/mutter-common-bin_46.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/46.1-2ubuntu1/+build/28374184/+files/mutter-common_46.1-2ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
Log in again or reboot.

I've just disabled the "Ubuntu tiling assistant" extension, and it seems to work fine for me.
I don't know if there is some side effect of manually installing the mutter update.

For me, the issue was a Pano - Clipboard Manager gnome extension.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5278/pano/
I had the pre-release version from github: https://github.com/oae/gnome-shell-pano/releases/tag/v23-alpha
After removing it, the issue is gone.
